# Swift 3: How to set all struct properties to nil

Tags: struct, swift3

Is there a better way to set all struct properties to nil than manually setting each properties to nil?

If I have a Hello struct

```
struct Hello {
    var salutation: String?
    var name: String?

}

let hello = Hello(salutation: "Mr.", name: "James")
```

Currently I am doing this to reset the values:

```
func removeAll() {
    salutation = nil
    name = nil
}
```

I'm sort of finding a better way especially when the struct is big.

I see some recommendation to use Mirror but I got error "Cannot assign to property: '$0' is immutable"

```
func removeAll() {

        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)

        let properties = mirror.children.flatMap { $0.value = nil }
    }
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the struct instance with a new one. Example:

```
var hello = Hello(salutation: "Mr.", name: "James")
// ... use it for a while ...
hello = Hello() // bingo!
```

All the Optional properties are now reset to `nil`.

You're even allowed to do this from *within* Hello, replacing `self` with a clean copy:

```
struct Hello {
    var salutation: String?
    var name: String?
    mutating func removeAll() {
        self = Hello()
    }
}

var hello = Hello(salutation: "Mr.", name: "James")
// ... use it for a while ...
hello.removeAll() // bingo
```

Comment: Hi Matt, on playground it's fine but within Xcode, I got warning: `Value of optional type Hello? not unwrapped; did you mean to use ! or ?`
Is it safe to use '!' here?

I added the mutating func just like your example.

Comment: I don't know what your "within Xcode" code looks like. I assure you there's nothing about what I said that would result in an "optional type `Hello?`", so it must be some complication you yourself have added.

Comment: Yes, I guessed that might be the case.